# Change Wordpress date format for comments in Astra

Tags: php, wordpress, date, formatting, comments

my problem is very simple but I am not familiar with PHP. My goal is to change the date format for the comments in my Wordpress blog from "26th of February 2021 at 12:23" to "43 minutes ago".

I also found a code snippet that does this for me, but it doesn't render the markup like the code which is provided by the theme itself.

**This is the code provided by Astra:**

```
printf(
    '<div class="ast-comment-time ast-col-lg-12"><span  class="timendate"><a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a></span></div>',
    esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
    esc_attr( get_comment_time( 'c' ) ),
    /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
    esc_html( sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'astra' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() ) ),
);
```

This is the code I found:

```
printf( _x( '%1$s ago', '%2$s = human-readable time difference', 'wpdocs_textdomain' ),
    human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ),
    current_time( 'timestamp' )
);
```

I'd be more than happy if someone could help me with this since I don't know where to search for a solution anymore...

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This revision to your code may work as desired:

```
printf(
    
   '<div class="ast-comment-time ast-col-lg-12">
       <span class="timendate"><a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a> 
       </span>
    </div>',

    esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),

    esc_attr( get_comment_time( 'c' ) ),

    esc_html( __( human_time_diff( get_comment_time( 'U' ) ) . ' ago', 'astra' ) )
);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! This worked perfectly :)